# How to combine bool query with interval query or any other query

Tags: elasticsearch, data-science, elastic-stack

I have indexed data into **elasticsearch**.

I want to query combination of [Boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with [Interval query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-intervals-query.html#intervals-match) .

If it is possible to combine two queries like this then also tell me if **_score** will be the combination of the two or not.

I am trying to make a query like this:

```
GET trademark28/_search?explain=true
{
  "size": 100, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "tm_applied_for_anan": {
              "query": "7 o' clock",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }, 
    "intervals" : {
      "tm_applied_for_only_char_without_space" : {
        "all_of" : {
          "intervals" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "query" : "7 o' clock",
                "max_gaps" : 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

But this query is throwing error.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line" : 16,
        "col" : 5
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line" : 16,
    "col" : 5
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

But when i run following queries individually. They run perfectly fine.

```
GET trademark28/_search?explain=true
{
  "size": 100, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "tm_applied_for_anan": {
              "query": "7 o' clock",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
GET trademark28/_search?explain=true
{
  "size": 100, 
  "query": {
    "intervals" : {
      "tm_applied_for_only_char_without_space" : {
        "all_of" : {
          "intervals" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "query" : "7 o' clock",
                "max_gaps" : 0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Is there a way i can combine two types of queries like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries can be combined using must clause(AND) or should clause(OR).
Overall score is based on all queries execute. Using ?explain=true shows sum of score from both queries.

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "tm_applied_for_anan": {
              "query": "7 o' clock",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "intervals": {
            "tm_applied_for_only_char_without_space": {
              "all_of": {
                "intervals": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "query": "7 o' clock",
                      "max_gaps": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```